# Django Rest Framework - How to get the json response in a way, so that it is easier to access in frontend?

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hey guys I have this serializer to get the list of pending users,

```
class UserInfo(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model       = Account
        fields      = ['id', 'username',]

class PendingRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    other_user  = UserInfo(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PendingRequest
        fields = ['other_user', ]
```

views.py

```
class PendingRequestListApiView(APIView):
    permission_classes      = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
       user                 = PendingRequest.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
       serializer           = PendingRequestSerializer(user, many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I am getting the json response like this.

```
[
{
    "other_user": {
        "id": 8,
        "username": "testuser5"
    }
},
{
    "other_user": {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "testuser2"
    }
}
```

]

I want the json response to look like this instead.

```
"results": [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "testuser2",
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "username": "testuser5",
    }
]
```

That is instead of having the user information in separate other_user, is it possible to combine it like it is in the second response?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [`to_representation()`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) method of `PendingRequestSerializer` to return the `other_user` value

```
class PendingRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        
    class Meta:
        model = PendingRequest

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return UserInfo(instance.other_user).data
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! can you please tell me what `to_representation` did there?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear it worked. `to_representation()` is where the serialization is done - in this case where it is converted to JSON. By overriding the method, you tell it to return the serialized data of `UserInfo` class instead of `PendingRequestSerializer`.